# How do i setup a simple smart dns proxy service using nginx?

Tags: dns, https, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have trying to setup a smart dns proxy service using nginx reverse proxy mode. its ok with http sites but i have issues with https sites. when i want to open https sites via my proxy i got following error message in my web browser:

```
An error occurred during a connection to example.com.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

also i have created a self signed certificate on my server it resolved above error but introduced new error such as follow

```
www.example.com uses an invalid security certificate.
 
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.
 
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

here is my simplified nginx.conf:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;
   
   server_name www.example.com example.com;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.com.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.com.key;
   ssl_verify_client off;

   location / {
      proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
 }
}
```

edit:
I forgot to say i have setup a nameserver which resolve considered site addresses to my nginx reverse proxy server address.

thanks

Comment: Why you want to proxy_pass https? why not just http?

Comment: Because most sites these days use https, also sites which i want to proxy use https too

Comment: Your proxied site is a public site?

Comment: Yes it is a public site

Comment: okay then, did you try my answer? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: no, unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: What do you mean by "DNS proxy?" It looks like you want to set up a reverse HTTPS proxy to me. If you actually want to proxy a DNS you should probably use a DNS server.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `a smart dns proxy service`. A [reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) is for the HTTP protocol and handles HTTP requests, not DNS. Please include example URLs and whether this is for a single site. Also, please note that [advanced server administration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions are really best asked over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) (unless it involves a control panel).

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore the SSL verification by turning off `proxy_ssl_verify`.

Here is an example

```
location / {
     proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
     proxy_ssl_verify              off;
}
```

You can check other option in [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html), an example you can also use `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` to define trusted proxied ssl.

But I think if the target proxy server can be accessed by nginx server only, l it's better using http instead https. From my experience it's faster.